# How do I convert a single vertical row into multiple row array in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, transpose

I am currently trying to convert a single vertical row in Excel into an array in multiple rows of 5.  So, for example I have

```
A1 1000
A2 1001
A3 1002
A4 1003
A5 1004
A6 1005
A7 1006
...
```

And I'm trying to convert it to a multiple row array like below:

```
1000 1001 1002 1003 1004
1005 1006 ...
```

I had previously done this in Excel but I cannot remember how I did it.  I used the TRANSPOSE function but I cannot remember the logic on how to shift the reference by 5 on the next row.  Does someone know a function I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMNS($A:A)+5*(ROWS($1:1)-1),0)
```

and copy both across and downward:

[image]

Comment: beat me by 20 seconds.

Comment: I might have used OFFSET, but there's more than one way to skin a cat... I think.

Comment: I was thinking that the index function would be helpful but did not think of this strategy.  Tried this and it worked wonderfully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Select your vertical row. Copy all row with CTRL+C. Click any empty cell. Right-click on mouse. Click s and click Enter.

Or click with mouse. Like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HCii.jpg